# How do I escape bracket in makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How do I escape bracket in makefile info? See my example:

```
$(info "gcc found :)")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally you should use curly braces if you have embedded parentheses:

```
${info "gcc found :)"}
```

But, you can escape almost anything like this by putting it in a variable:

```
CP := )

$(info "gcc found :$(CP)")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BRACKET = :)
$(info "gcc found $(BRACKET)")
```

Comment: Why do you need `EMPTY` here?

Comment: Yeah, they're superfluous.